# Does anyone know how to export a Sims 4 character into mmd?

Tags: modeling

I tired using Direct X and exporting it as an OBJ file and a dae then going back into blender to export it as a direct x

When I go into PMD it either won't let me import it or only the legs show up with no color

I got the entire body in their one time but it was still completely grey

I saw a few people  accomplish this. I tired to ask them but they either ignored me

Or told me it was "a secret." Sigh...

Idk if anyone knows what I'm talking about i don't know I'm allowed to post links This is my first time using this website

This is what I'm trying to do
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UzM_KOUrl0Q